# Finding and deleting an element from a vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<unsigned int> x;
vector<unsigned int>::iterator itr;
unsigned int varF;
...
....

// find and delete an element from a vector.
itr = std::find(x.begin(), x.end(), varF);  // <algorithm>
if (itr != x.end()) 
x.erase(itr);
//or
x.erase(std::remove(x.begin(), x.end(), varF), x.end());
```

I want to convert this vector to a vector of pointers

```
vector<unsigned int*> x;
```

How I can convert the above functionality for a vector of pointers?

Comment: Why do you think you need pointers?

Comment: It should look absolutely the same. What exactly goes wrong for you? The only notice is that perhaps you need to free a pointer before/after removing it from the vector.

Answer (score 8):

Use `find_if` instead of `find`, or `remove_if` instead of `remove`, to employ a custom predicate:

```
struct FindIntFromPointer
{
  FindIntFromPointer(int i) : n(i) { }
  bool operator()(int * p) const { return n == *p; }
private:
  int n;
};

std::find_if(x.begin(), x.end(), FindIntFromPointer(varF));
x.erase(std::remove_if(x.begin(), x.end(), FindIntFromPointer(varF)), x.end());
```

If you have C++11, you can use a lambda instead of the explicit predicate:

```
std::find_if(x.begin(), x.end(), [varF](int * p) -> bool { return varF == *p; });
```

The predicate could be turned into a template if you want to reuse it for other similar situations where you need to dereference-and-compare. If this is the case, a template is more elegant than typing out the lambdas each time.

Comment: @user986789: No worries. Feel free to hit that "accept" button if you find the answer useful :-)